# Airflow import error - broken dag message in UI

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I've modified a DAG file and in the UI I see that it started complaining on an import stmt with BROKEN DAG msg. Strange thing is that import was previously present and was working fine before my change. I am able to list_dag (CLI), run this DAG tasks manually and I dont see any issues with the DAG file. Wondering how do I fix this issue please?

I looked at the metadata table import_error and I see this message is present and the “id” column is being updated constantly. Hence I am not sure even the deletion of the row from this import_error table would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete restart of all the components fixed it. Didn't have to do resetdb.